# Forward c3po log into file at Logback

Tags: java, spring, logback

c3po logs are printed console usually. I tried to forwaRD C3PO LOGS into a file, but does not make it possible

here is my logback.xml and pom.xml

**LOGBACK**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration scanPeriod="10 seconds" debug="false" scan="true">
    <property name="LOG_DIR" value="logs" />
    <appender name="STDOUTAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%X{traceid}] - %C{1}:%L %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <appender name="SPRING"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOG_DIR}/spring.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/spring.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}
            </FileNamePattern>

            <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%X{traceid}] - %C{1}:%L %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="errorAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOG_DIR}/error/ERROR.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/error/ERROR.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}
            </FileNamePattern>

            <MaxHistory>72</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="AppAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOG_DIR}/application/APPLICATION.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/application/APPLICATION.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}
            </FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%X{traceid}] - %C{1}:%L %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="TxnAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOG_DIR}/txn/TXN.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/txn/TXN.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}
            </FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="AlarmAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOG_DIR}/alarm/ALARM.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/alarm/ALARM.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
            </FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="C3POAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOG_DIR}/c3po/c3po.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/c3po/c3po.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
            </FileNamePattern>

            <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="SPRING" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="TxnLogger">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="TxnAppender" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="AlarmLogger">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="AlarmAppender" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0">
        <appender-ref ref="C3POAppender" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.ttech.pnsender" additivity="true" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="AppAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="errorAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUTAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ahmetk</groupId>
<artifactId>pnsender</artifactId>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>




    </plugins>



</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- weblogic üzerine deploy etmek için websocket collision olmasin. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

org.apache.tomcat.embed
            tomcat-embed-websocket
            provided
         -->

```
<!-- to ensure that the embedded servlet container doesn’t interfere with the servlet container -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Push Notification API for IOS devices -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.notnoop.apns</groupId>
        <artifactId>apns</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Beta7_2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relayrides</groupId>
        <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
        <version>0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- KAFKA-QUEUE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<!--weblogic deployment 3.2.1 ile çalıştı  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- TESTING- EMBEDEED DB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: does ${LOG_DIR}/c3po folder has any permission restriction?

Comment: nope, other appender works properly, even  c3po/c3po.log file is created,

Comment: could not forward the log into the file, for now I just disabled c3p0 logging temporarly com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_LEVEL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got similar issue when using slf4j + logback + c3p0 combination.

Found solution as below steps:

1. Let c3p0 (MLog) pick `java 1.4+ standard logging`, no action needed for this. Automaticly picks `if you dont configure FallbackMLog
2. Add dependency `org.slf4j / jul-to-slf4j` to your pom.xml (bridging java util logging to slf4j)
3. On your main, before c3p0 initialization add below code fragment:

   ```
   // Getting JUL root logger
   Logger logger = java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");

   // Remove already attached Console handler which is responsible for above trouble
   for (Handler handler : logger.getHandlers()) {
       handler.close();
       logger.removeHandler(handler);
   }

   // Let SLF4J bridge configure its own handler(s)
   SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
   ```

Comment: slf4j support is a c3p0 0.9.5 feature. There's a performance issue (unnecessary allocation of Strings) with slf4j support prior to versions 0.9.5.2.

More details on how to set Slf4j up for MLog and other bridges:  https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_logging

Adding the word logback for indexing purposes.